# crossfilter to do word frequency

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I would like a crossfilter group that gives the word frequency and average rating for each word in a series of surveys so that I can make an awesome interactive word-bubble-frequency chart.

My data looks like:

```
[{feedback: "This is a horrible service", rating:2},
{feedback: "I love everything about everything", rating: 10},
{feedback: "love the user interface, good service", rating:6},
{feedback: "", rating: 7} ]
```

I would like something like:

```
[ {key: love, count:2, ave: 8}, {key: horrible, count:1, rating:2 }, {key: service, 
count: 2, rating: 4 } ,.... ]
```

So far I have:

function to break up string into tokens, returns object with frequency for each word

```
var wordcnt = function(bah ){
     var hist = {}, words =  bah.split(/[\s*\.*\,\;\+?\#\|:\-\/\\\[\]\(\)\{\}$%&0-9*]/)
     for( var i in  words)
        if(words[i].length >1 )
            hist[words[i]] ? hist[words[i]]+=1 : hist[words[i]]=1;
                return hist;
   };
```

Loading data into d3 and crossfilter

```
  d3.csv("test.csv",  function( error, data) {

   data.forEach(function(d) {
           d.rating= +d.rating;     
       d.wordCount= wordcnt(d.feedback.toLowerCase());   
    });


var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var all = ndx.groupAll();

var frequencyDimension=ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.wordCount; });
```

And one butchered group reduce function!

```
var frequencyGroup= frequencyDimension.group().reduce(
     function (p, v) {
   for (var key in v.wordCount) {  
    if (v.frequency.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                p.frequency[key]+= v[key];
                    p.frequency[key].count++;
                    p.frequency[key].sum+= v.rating ;

              }
            else{
                 p.frequency[key]=v[key];
                 p.frequency[key].count=1;
                 p.frequency[key].sum = v.rating;
            }
        }       
           p.frequency[key].ave = p.frequency[key].sum/p.frequency[key].count ;
       return p;
    },
     function (p, v) {
        for (var key in v.wordCount) {
              if (v.frequency.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                p.frequency[key]-= v[key];
                    p.frequency[key].count--;
                    p.frequency[key].sum-= v.rating ;

              }
        //don't need an else statement because can't remove key if it doesn't exist
       }
        p.frequency[key].ave = p.frequency[key].sum/p.frequency[key].count ;

        return p;
     },
     function (p,v)  {
          return    { frequency: {} } ; 
      } 
 )
```

Comment: I think rather than using the standard dimension.group(), you should look at the dimension.groupAll(), which gives you complete control over the structure of your grouping. It's not well-documented, but it should allow you to re-build the histogram you are building in your wordcnt function, but incrementally for the entire dataset.

Comment: So use  group = frequencyDimension.groupAll().reduce() ?  What would my reduce function look like?  I can't seem to get anything out of .value() besides the number of survey responses.

Comment: The structure of the .reduce() functions for groupAll() is different than normal. As I said, it's not well-documented :-). Can you set up a jsFiddle or something similar with your current code and I can fix you up with an example?

Comment: I used d3.set to get a list of unique words in each survey response and to get a master list of all words in all surveys, which I then used to make my initial reduce in group reduce.  http://jsfiddle.net/imfatandugly/Nh3m9/

Comment: This is more or less the right idea. I would just move all of your code within the init function of your .reduce() and use the actual word as your grouping key in a d3.map() instead of using the index, but I think the way you've got it set up is pretty efficient despite the external references (I can't run it to test as I get a syntax error).

Comment: cool, thanks for your help Ethan.  I don't know whats up with the syntax error, I couldn't get it running either :(  .  Works for my real data but it's super slow.  Do you think it makes sense to turn words( which is an array of all the words in my feedback) into a dimension?

Comment: It's running now - http://jsfiddle.net/Nh3m9/2/  If it is slow with your full data set, then I suggest you definitely do everything within the reduce functions. Nothing outside. Then it should be possible to optimize so that it runs quickly.

Comment: @MichaelHiggins, did you get it working at the end with an ok enough speed?